# In Trading view, Trigger alert when inverted hammer/hammer formed at my marked levels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, trading, pine-script-v4

I want to create an alert when a hammer/inverted hammer forms at my marked level.

Ex:
Taking one input parameter and a custom level is marked.
Now if an inverted hammer forms at my level then it should trigger the alert.
[image]

Below is my code for finding an inverted hammer

```
C_InvertedHammerBullishNumberOfCandles = 1
C_InvertedHammerBullish = false
if C_SmallBody and C_Body > 0 and C_BodyHi < hl2 and C_UpShadow >= C_Factor * C_Body and lower_wick<=lower_body
    //and not C_HasDnShadow 
    if C_DownTrend
        C_InvertedHammerBullish := true
alertcondition(C_InvertedHammerBullish, title = "Inverted Hammer – Bullish", message = "New Inverted Hammer – Bullish pattern detected")
if C_InvertedHammerBullish and not C_Doji and  InvertedHammerInput and (("Bullish" == CandleType) or CandleType == "Both") and CandlePatternInput and bearish
    label.new(bar_index, patternLabelPosHigh, text="IH", style=label.style_label_down, color = label_color_bearish, textcolor=color.white,size=size.small)
```

Note: The alert needs to be triggered only after the candle has closed and the pattern has been formed.

Timeframe : 3 mins

Thanks in advance.